# NoMethodError? Counting Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, aggregate-functions

I have the following models:

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :label
  has_many :products
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks

  def self.releases_count
   self.count(:all)
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release

  has_many :releases_tracks, :through => :release, :source => :tracks      
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks

  def self.products_count
   self.count(:all)
  end
 end
```

On my label/index view i'm able to display a count of the Releases absolutely fine using:

```
 <%= label.releases.releases_count %>
```

I'm trying to do the same for Products using:

```
 <%= label.releases.products.products_count %>
```

But get a NoMethodError:

```
 undefined method `products' for #<Label:0x10ff59690>
```

Any ideas?

I have lots of other aggregations I want to perform (Track Counts etc) so some guidance on where I'm going wrong would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need define your production/Label association

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases
  has_many :products, :through => :releases
end
```

Comment: Wow, I should really have worked that out myself! In my mind as Label/Release and then Release/Product were associated, I thought I could access via label.release.product. One small change I made was to then access using <%= label.products.products_count %>. Thanks for the help!!